# Losing termstore metadata when we move files from library to another

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, move

Environment: SharePoint online with Modern libraries

I am trying to move document from one document library to another by using "Move to" function available in modern experience for lists and libraries.

In my document library i am having few columns which are managed metadata. When document moved to different document library then it is moving the document with properties like Lookup, Choice, single line of text values but except Managed Metadata column values.

Is there any limitation to Move functionality?

But same thing is working perfectly if I do "Copy to" functionality.

How I can retain the Termstore values when I do the Move to functionality?

Comment: Are the columns between the two libraries exactly the same? Do they point to the same branch in the same termset?

Comment: Yes true. I have same set of columns and Managed Metadata columns are pointing to same term sets

Comment: When i use copy to option then it is working fine. But not working with Move to option

Comment: when i use the Move it doesn't work either, when i use the Copy it sometimes swaps terms during the copy

Comment: @dc2009 are you sure? we haven't faced that issue. if that is the case that will be a serious issue then

Comment: @Mihir yes i ran a lot of tests, it occurs both with MM list fields and MM fields inherited from a content type, all pointing at the same termset; the values don't get copied over properly

Comment: @dc2009 but it is not happening for us

Comment: I am late to the party, but I am getting exactly the same - it is not moving metadata across.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by Backup and Restore

Backup site:

```
Backup-SPSite -Identity "http://sp2103dev/sites/abc/" -Path "C:\MMS\sitetoarchive.bak"
```

Restore site:

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity "http://sp2013/sites/xyz" -Path "C:\MMS\sitetoarchive.bak" -force
```

Migrate SharePoint Managed Metadata to another farm or Service Application
http://expert-advice.org/sharepoint/migrate-sharepoint-managed-metadata-to-another-farm/

Comment: Are you sure this will work in SP online?

Comment: this will work for on prem SP only, and moves the files from one site collection to another, not to another library